# How can I get the 'read-only' property of a win32 edit box?

Tags: win32gui, editcontrol

How can I get the 'read-only' property of a win32 edit box ?

And I know how to set the property. code like this.

`SendDlgItemMessage(g_hwnd, IDC_EDIT_1, EM_SETREADONLY, 1, 0);`

But how can I know this edit control has the 'read-only' property ?
I mean not MFC\CWND or some how, just win32 method, like SendMessage api.

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> EM_SETREADONLY message
>
> Sets or removes the read-only style (ES_READONLY) of an edit control.

So just read that style from your control using GetWindowLongPtr() with GWL_STYLE.

Here is the Win API call:

```
bool bRO = ::GetWindowLongPtr(::GetDlgItem(g_hwnd, IDC_EDIT_1), GWL_STYLE) & ES_READONLY;
```

Comment: And for things defined as `CWnd*` variables: `bool bRO = ::GetWindowLongPtr(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE) & ES_READONLY;`